# Avada Builder Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress

I have created some custom posts using the Custom Post Type Maker plugin. I am trying to use these custom posts within avada and fusion builder. I am using Avada 7.2 (latest version) and I have found this documentation which explains you can select this in the post types section. This option does not exist for me, is it not an option with the newest version?

https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/avada-builder/avada-builder-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 4):

It appears the theme developers changed the location of the link to this option somewhere between version 7.1 and 7.2 (not exactly clear to me from their [changelog](https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/installation-maintenance/avada-changelog/), but they mention usability improvements in several places).

Avada's [theme documentation on enabling their builder on custom post types](https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/avada-builder/avada-builder-custom-post-types/) is still correct, but in my opinion the first step could benefit from a screenshot. To get to 'Builder Options' you need to first go to the Avada theme dashboard, and there, next to the Avada logo, hover over 'Options'. In the submenu that comes up you can now choose 'Builder Options'. Now you can find post type checkboxes towards the bottom of the page.

Here is what it looks like for me in Avada version 7.4:

[image: Avada Builder Options]

Comment: This answer is still correct as of Avada V7.8.1

Answer (score 2):

I found out where, the layout is different with the new installation. You need to hover over options and select builder options.

Comment: Thank you! Thought I looked everywhere but this worked for me.